# values not show in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

i try to add values in dropdownlist in gridview query works fine but it appears as this ..
[image]

gridview html

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ApproveID" DataField="ApproveID" ></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

                   <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# 
             Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server"
           class="vpb_dropdown">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

code

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Find the DropDownList in the Row
            DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList4") as
                  DropDownList);
            ddlCountries.DataSource = GetData("SELECT ApproveID,ApproveType FROM
           ApproveType");
            ddlCountries.DataTextField = "ApproveType";
            ddlCountries.DataValueField = "ApproveID";
            ddlCountries.DataBind();

            //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

            //Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList
            //string country = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
            //ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

values are not inside in dropdownlist ..how to show values in dropdown??
and when i debug the code it cant show me any error

getdata code

```
private DataSet GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check you GetData() function.Is it returning Data ?

Comment: i update get data in code plz see update code..

Comment: Can you show your GetData() code ?

Comment: yes i update in question...plz see above

Comment: Please check that it is really returning any data. You code looks ok.

Comment: But have you checked if `GetData()` returns any data?

Comment: when i set a breakpoint and move cursor on ds it shows me system.data.dataset

Comment: you can check row in ds like this ds= GetData();if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0){ //code to set drop dowm list}

Comment: ok now i have a values in gridview

now the probelm is that when i comment on this code it works fine

string type= (e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
                ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(type).Selected = true;

but when dont comment then error occur on last line

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Have you inspected the `DataSet`? Does it contain a record with a `Value` that is equal to `country`?
Or you could write `if (ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country) != null) { ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Some Value";
```

then you will get the value as default

Answer (score 0):

Get data function returns null or empty value so it wont through error or exception while debugging.Your code working fine better check data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In a project I participated we returned the DataTable instead of DataSet and it was working fine with dropdowns. We had code like this:

```
if( ds.Tables.Count == 1)
    return ds.Tables[0];
else
    return new DataTable();
```

Besides I would change the way of databinding. In my opinion using ObjectDataSource is a better approach becuase the event is called only when the data is needed and you don't have to do checks like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

After your last comment you should check if the `DataSet` contains the record you want ot set as selected:

```
if (ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country) != null) 
{ 
   ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true; 
}
```